# How to update data in local json file in flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, offline

I'm the junior flutter developer, and I would like to seek your support.
Currently, I would need to update data in a local JSON file in Flutter as below.

```
{"title":"ករណី ពិនិត្យផ្ទៃពោះ",
"lists":[
  {
     "id":"127",
     "faci_code":"20018",
     "y_txt":"2022",
     "m_txt":"1",
     "ind_id":"1",
     "qty":"100",
     "rec_by":"od123456",
     "rec_date":"2022-06-27 13:50:31",
     "lock_txt":"0",
     "sec_id":"1",
     "ind_num":"1",
     "ind_eng":"# of ANC 1",
     "ind_kh":"ចំនួនស្រ្ដីបានពិនិត្យផ្ទៃពោះលើកទី១ទាំងអស់",
     "HFAC_NAME":"Boeng Pram",
     "HFAC_NAMEKh":"បឺងប្រាំ",
     "OD_CODE":"201",
     "OD_NAME":"Thma Koul",
     "OD_NAME_KH":"ថ្មគោល",
     "PRO_CODE":"2",
     "PROVINCE":"Battambang",
     "PROVINCE_KH":"បាត់ដំបង"
}]}
```

I have searched and tried multiple solutions, but I couldn't resolve this issue yet. 
I hope someone can provide a solution in advance.

Regard, thanks.

Comment: I want to update the "qty":"100" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't right files in project folders.

Try local storage.

I used path_provider package in this example for get application directory path to write json file on local storage.

### 1. Create data class

#### Note. this data class should match your stored json structure

```
class DataClass {
  String name;
  int age;

  DataClass(this.name, this.age);

  factory DataClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataClass(json['name'], json['age']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'age': age,
    };
  }
}
```

### 2.create and update json file

```
DataClass? updateJson;


  void createJson() async {
    String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    File jsonFile = File("${appDocDir.path}/data.json");

    jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(data);
    updateJson = DataClass.fromJson(jsonDecode(data));
    setState(() {});
  }

  void updateJsonFile() async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File jsonFile = File("${appDocDir.path}/data.json");

    //update
    final jsonAsString = jsonFile.readAsStringSync();
    updateJson = DataClass.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonAsString));
    updateJson?.name = "updated name";
    updateJson?.age = _counter;
    jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(jsonEncode(updateJson?.toJson()));
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean to write the json in local storage, am i right?

Comment: yes. Use sqflite package and stores all the values in columns.

Comment: could you help to share some concepts?

Comment: i updated the answer with example